# Python. No way to make fast_float from None error

Tags: python, plot, sage

I wrote this function.

```
def f(t):
  if 0<t<pi:
    return 1
  elif t==pi:
    return 0
  elif gp(pi)<t<2*pi:
    return -1
```

When I calculate value everything is ok, but when I try to build plot I get an "no way to make fast_float from None" error.

```
pl5 = plot(f(t),(0,3))
show(pl5)
```

What could be the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `t` in your input?

Comment: It means that `t` satisfies neither of those conditions. Do you have a default fallback in case this happens? If so add a `return` at the bottom of your code.

Comment: What should `f` return if `t` equals `None`?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely problem is that all three conditions are false, so the function is implicitly returning `None`.

For example, what happens when `t == 0` or when `t >= 2*pi`?

Answer (score 2):

The only way your code can fail to give you a NameError is if `t` is already defined:

```
sage: pl5 = plot(f(t),(0,3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-1f9b723e1faf> in <module>()
----> 1 pl5 = plot(f(t),(Integer(0),Integer(3)))

NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

Let's assume `t` is an Expression.  Then, since arguments are evaluated 
before they're passed, you're really trying to plot `None`, because none of the branches of your function are True for a symbolic expression:

```
sage: t = var("t")
sage: print f(t)
None
sage: plot(None,(0,3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-5b43a830d374> in <module>()
----> 1 plot(None,(Integer(0),Integer(3)))
[...]
TypeError: no way to make fast_float from None
```

Just leave the `t` off if you want to plot the function.  Note that I've changed the range from `(0,3)` to `(0,6`) so we at least see something interesting.

```
sage: pl5 = plot(f,(0,6))
sage: pl5.save("pl5.png")
```

[image: example picture]

---

Aside: I don't know what your `gp(pi)` is supposed to do-- there's not really a need to get Pari involved here.  Simply use `pi`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `t` satisfies neither of those conditions. Do you have a default fallback in case this happens? If so add a `return` at the bottom of your code.

```
def f(t):
  if 0<t<pi:
    return 1
  elif t==pi:
    return 0
  elif gp(pi)<t<2*pi:
    return -1
  return -3  # if it's -3 you will know t is satisfying none of the previous conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function f is returning None.

The reason is, that when all three conditions fail, no return statement is given at all. Python will return None in such cases.

Either add a return statement with a numeric value at the end of f or change the conditions, so that every case will be covered.

To prevent this, you can also choose (recommended) to (in such cases) always have an else-part (at least when unsure, if all cases are covered):

```
if ....
   ...
elif ...

...
else: # all the rest will be caught here
   return some_value
```